# jQuery Switch Case if contains a class name

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple HTML elements which when clicked bring up an iframed form (can't use AJAX on this project). Instead of creating a bunch of different forms specific to each item I would like to pass in a token via the URL which quietly gets recorded in the form so that I know which item they clicked.

```
        $('.Item a').click(function() {

            var className = $(this).attr('class');
            console.log("you clicked " + className);
            switch(className){
                case 'item1':
                $("#myiframe").attr('src', "form.php?token1");
                console.log("url changed to token1");

           }
        });
```

The issue is that some of the `a` tags have multiple classes. How can I change the switch case to the syntactically correct equivalent function of: `case:contains 'item1':`?

Comment: You can't use a `switch` here.  You can do `if($(this).hasClass('item1')){}`.

Comment: I was afraid of that and was hoping for the visually cleaner `case`

Comment: `switch` and `case` are only good when a variable can *equal* different values.

Answer (score 3):

I think the switch statement is not best suited for this:

You can use the [`hasClass` method](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/), and do something like this:

```
$('.Item').on('click', 'a', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('item1')){
        $("#myiframe").attr('src', "form.php?token1");
        console.log("url changed to token1");        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you realy want to use `switch`, and unless you really need to use class, set a data attribute equal to the token value for each item and where you are setting the className variable set a token variable instead and switch on that.

something like:

```
$('.Item a').click(function() {

        var token = $(this).data('token');
        console.log("you clicked " + token);
        switch(token){
            case 'item1':
            $("#myiframe").attr('src', "form.php?token1");
            console.log("url changed to token1");

       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than look at the full text of the attribute `class` you can use `is(selector)`

```
$('.Item a').click(function() {    
     if($(this).is('.item1'){
        /* do something when class = item1*/
     }
});
```

Or target classes more specifically in the initial selector

```
$('.Item a.item1').click...
```